# How to fix merge conflicts many commits ago while keeping one branch?

Tags: git, merge, version-control, tortoisegit, merge-conflict-resolution

In the team I am in, we agree to have only one branch - master branch in central repository. We create feature branch but we never push. Some developers forget to `rebase` their feature branches before `merge` to master. So there is conflict in Git and they do not bother to resolve. (They just use theirs to overwrite others change.) Some other commits come in and sit on top of those conflict merge. That makes the central repository to have more than one branch.

Here is a simplified example. It is similar to what is available in TortoiseGit. The name inside `()` is branch name. As this is just example, I push as well (those feature branch has 'origin' in front of its name).

So how to resolve merge conflicts while keeping only one branch - the master branch?

```
*   (feature/feature04, master, origin/master, origin/feature/feature04) Commit in feature 04
|
*   Merge branch 'feature/feature03'
|\
| *   (feature/feature03, origin/feature/feature03) Commit in feature 03
* |   (feature/feature02, origin/feature/feature02) Commit in feature 02
|/
*   (feature/feature01, origin/feature/feature01) Commit in feature 01
|
*   Commit #1
```

Another view of same graph:

```
A -- B -- C ------ E -- F -- (other commits)   MASTER branch
      \------ D --/                            feature03 branch
```

Comment: Your question is unlear, what do you mean by keep merge conflicts? - After merging the conflicts are solved.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the commit history as linear for remote repo, you should replace commit `E` with commit `D` in the commit history (as below graph).

```
A---B---C---E---F---…X  master
     \     /
      --D--             feature/feature03
```

**First, rebase commit `D` on the top of commit `C` and point commit `feature/feature03` to the rebased commit** by:

```
git rebase --onto <commit id for C> <commit id for B> <commit id for D>
git branch -f feature/feature03
```

Then the commit history will be:

```
          D'   feature/feature03
         /
A---B---C---E---F---…---X  master
     \     /
      --D--
```

**Then rebase other commits on `master` branch on the top of the commit `D'` and re-point `master` branch** by below commands:

```
git rebase --onto <commit id for D'> <commit id for E> <commit id for X>
git branch -f master
git checkout master
```

Then the commit history will be (feature/feature03 branch point to commit `D'`, master branch point to commit`X'`):

```
A---B----C---D'---F'---…---X'  master
             |
      Feature/feature03
```

**Finally force push the changed commit history of `master` branch to remote repo** by the command:

```
git push -f origin master
```

**Note:** the feature branches seems already pushed to remote repo, since you showed the tracking branches like `origin/feature/feature01`,`origin/feature/feature02` etc. If you want to delete the feature branches in remote repo, you can use `git push :feature/feature01`,  `git push :feature/feature02` etc.